# Cyclicity:To find the units digit of a number

Tags: chinese-remainder-theorem

> Can you please help me to find the units digit of this number:
>   33^34^35^36^37^38 .. I got this question in CSR 2017

Comment: Look at $\mod 10$

Comment: I don't understand what the number is.  Is it finite?

Comment: nope#lulu, it just goes on like 33^34^35^36^37^38^39^40^41^42^43^44^45^46^47^48.....

Comment: I don't know what the units place of infinity means.

Comment: can you please explain this more clearly( look at mod 10 )#kingW3

Comment: i mean what will the units place come when this number is simplified

Comment: oh i am so sorry lulu thats not the ques

Comment: yeas this is a  finite number i just edited the question

Comment: Ok.  Hint:   $a\equiv b\pmod {10}\implies a^c\equiv b^c \pmod {10}$.  Also $c\equiv d \pmod 4\implies a^c\equiv a^d\pmod {10}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57351/discussion-between-rajsingh-and-lulu).

Comment: Sorry, I don't go into chat rooms.  That hint should be enough.  Just go step by step.  figure out $33^{34} \pmod {10}$ and so on.

Comment: can you please tell me lulu that from where is this mod 10 coming from??

Comment: The units place of an integer $n$ is the same as $n\pmod {10}$.

Comment: and can you please upvote this question for me to get my student badge

Comment: No problem, done.

Comment: oh yes now i understand

Answer (score 2):

$33^4\equiv 3^4\equiv 81\equiv 1\pmod{10}$.

$34^{35^{36^{37^{38}}}}=4k$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z^+$.

$33^{4k}\equiv \left(33^4\right)^k\equiv 1^k\equiv 1\pmod{10}$.

[Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) is relevant here, but I've been able to explain this simply without it.

---

Edit: The [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) of $33$ modulo $10$ is $4$.

You could use Euler's theorem to notice that $\phi(10)=4$ and continue.

To explain it more simply, notice the pattern:

$33^0\equiv 1\pmod{10}$

$33^1\equiv 3\pmod{10}$

$33^2\equiv 3^2\equiv 9\pmod{10}$

$33^3\equiv 3^3\equiv 27\equiv 7\pmod{10}$

$33^4\equiv 3^4\equiv 81\equiv 1\pmod{10}$

$33^5\equiv 33\cdot 33^4\equiv 33\cdot 1\equiv 3\pmod{10}$

...

Since $34^{35^{36^{37^{38}}}}$ is divisible by $4$, we get the answer $1$.

Comment: I agree with that conclusion, but I don't understand the reasoning.  Why do you look at $33^4$?  The first stage here appears (to me at least) to be $33^{34}\equiv 33^2 \equiv 3^2\equiv 9\pmod {10}$.  Or are you doing something else?

Comment: @lulu The [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) of $33$ mod $10$ is $4$. I didn't explain it carefully. The OP could just use Euler's theorem.

Comment: Ah, understood.  Perfectly sensible. (+1)

Comment: Or $\phi(10)=4$, Euler's theorem.